# WebSocket disconnect on .send()

Tags: jakarta-ee, websocket, glassfish-4

I'm trying to make a web server with Glassfish 4, and I'm using a WebSocket to communicate back and forth. The only problem is that whenever I try to send anything from my browser to the server, I get disconnected with an "RSV bit(s) incorrectly set" error on the server side, however the server can send stuff to the client no problem. I tested it from my phone, and that works fine. I'm using Safari 7.0.2 on OSX 10.9.2. I think the error might be that the browser is trying to use the "x-webkit-deflate-frame" extension, but I don't know for sure. What do you think could be causing this, and how do I fix it? If you need any more information to help, ask. I'm not sure what to include.

[EDIT] I forgot to mention that [this site](http://www.websocket.org/echo.html) is doing the same thing. Putting in onto wss works perfectly, but I can't figure out how to get that to work on my server.

[EDIT 2] I did more testing, and it seems to only fail to work when connecting from the same computer. Connecting from anywhere else works fine. Any ideas why this might be? I also tried other browsers on the same computer, and that didn't work either.

Thanks in advance,
-tlf

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try deploying [sample-echo](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.glassfish.tyrus.samples%7Ctyrus-sample-echo%7C1.5%7Cwar) project from Tyrus workspace and re-test?

I'm using similar setup for testing and I did not experience anything like that. Safari might use x-webkit-deflate-frame extension, but unless you modified ServerEndpointConfig.Configurator (to accept this extension), it won't be used by neither side.

If you are not able to make progress, please share minimal application which reproduces that issue to users@tyrus.java.net or as an issue on [TYRUS Jira](https://java.net/jira/browse/TYRUS).

Thanks!
Pavel

Comment: I updated the question with more information. Also, I don't know what you're talking about, sorry. I'm new to web development.

Comment: please share details about the application you are deploying locally as well as client code you use to access your localhost service.

Comment: Here is my project. https://github.com/thislooksfun/dj-request
I'm using Glassfish 4, deployed through Eclipse.